# How can add menu with child and nested child in ng2 admin template

Tags: angular

I want to add a menu in ng2 admin panel as like:

```
Main Menu
  ->sub Menu 1
      ->Sub Main menu 1
          ->add
          ->delete
          ->edit
      ->Sub Main menu 1
          ->add
          ->delete
          ->edit
  ->sub Menu 1
```

how can i do that?

Comment: What's your question? Just use routerLink to point to the right component?

Comment: I reckon he want to make a nested submenu. Wasn't that clear?

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible ways . 
As an example consider following navbar

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" [routerLink]="['home']" >WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a [routerLink]="['menu1']" >Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a [routerLink]="['menu1','menu1,'add']">Menu 1 / Add</a</li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

The **routerLink** is used to navigate to right route , you can use any html code and use the routerLink and ng2 routing to achieve the right solution.

1. create the routes
2. assign the appropriate components to the routes
3. use routerLink in your html to navigate to the routes

Visit [this link for router](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html)

Comment: He wants a nested submenu. Your example is only creating a submenu. To be honest, your example doesn't even make a sub menu it's just an item.

Comment: I am trying to explain that how to connect **html** , created menu with ng2 components , because that is the only ng2 part in the question . Rest is simple html code. My example is not the exact menu , but example item connecting to menu (route/component) and sub-menu (child-route/component)

Comment: I understand what you mean, we can interpret OP's question differently ofcourse. We can only wait for what he has to say.